# Column Grouping with Title in DataTables

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am creating an HTML table with **jQuery's DataTables** plug-in. I would like to know if there is a way to **group a number of columns together with a Title** which describes what the grouping represents.

In my specific case, 3 of my columns will display an address (Street, City, State). I'd like them to have an additional border around just those columns with a title that indicates to the end-user that those 3 columns represent the address.

I'm considering just changing the background color of those 3 columns which will do the job but I'm wanting the **Address** title to be displayed. I've seen that rows can be grouped together and sections divided by separators; however, I haven't yet come across anything that makes it possible to group columns together.

Comment: Are you asking if the data can be returned can be combined or the table/columns look different?

Comment: I'd like to organize the table after the data has been returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show group headers see this [example](https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/complex_header.html) (build the `<thead>` element using `colspan` and `rowspan`).

To show borders around you group build `CSS` classes with `border-left` and `border-right` and use the [columns.className](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.className) option for the first and last column in your group.